# Nested Select Query In MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hi I have two tables in my database. suppose table 1 has a name of login and table two has user_info

**Table Structure**

***login***

uid :   integer

user_name :  varchar

password : varchar

tbl_name :  varchar

***user_info***

id : int

name : varchar

.....

suppose in login table for uid =1 tble_name is user_info

then how can I get contens of user_info table from one query ?

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT login.tbl_name  FROM db.login  WHERE uid = 1 )as a
```

but this returns **"user_info"** is there any way to do this instead of writing two queries ?

Comment: Why do you store the name of a table at all? This seems like a bad design. Couldn't the query simply be written as `select * from login join user_info on login.uid = user_info.id`? Or maybe I'm missing something vital.

Comment: @jpw one application came form modification and I have to do this, no other way.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is using a dynamic statement, so perhaps using a prepared statement could work for you:

```
SET @id = 1;
SELECT @table := tbl_name from login where uid = @id;
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table, ' WHERE id = ', @id);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This would return the value for `id=1` in the table stored in the `tbl_name` column in the `login` table.